# How to publish a manifest file with Laravel Vapor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-vapor

I would like to publish the file `manifest.webmanifest` on Laravel Vapor. I've tried to serve it on the root domain ([docs](https://blog.laravel.com/vapor-serving-assets-from-root-domain)):

```php
# vapor.php
...
    'serve_assets' => ['manifest.webmanifest'],
...
```

Vapor handles that route, but throws an exception:

```
Client error: `GET https://xxxx.cloudfront.net/xxx/manifest.webmanifest` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
```

After further inspection this is logical, because the file is never send to the S3 bucket. It appears that `Laravel/VaporCli/AssetFiles` filters files like `*.webmanifest`, `manifest.json` and `mix-manifest.json`.

No clue why it does that. Does anyone have a trick to get the job done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A developer working on Vapor [replied](https://github.com/laravel/vapor-cli/commit/30f55eff6ebc22e30796e9e033536894a28b0824#commitcomment-46973546) and said changing it isn't possible right now because it will be a breaking change. He suggests adding a route that returns the content of the manifest.

I've added this route to my project:

```php
Route::middleware('cache.headers:public;max_age=7200')->get(
    '/manifest.webmanifest',
    function (): string {
        return file_get_contents(public_path('manifest.webmanifest'));
    }
)
```